# No root element found. Issue?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I've just wanted to use the XML-Serializer of the .NET framework(version 2.0).
I created to methods to serialize and deserialize my settings:

```
public static void Save(string filename)
{
    var settings = Settings.Instance;

    if (File.Exists(filename))
        File.Delete(filename);

    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        serializer.Serialize(stream, settings);
    }
}
```

The Save-methods works really fine and as a result I get the following xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EnableHooking>true</EnableHooking>
  <IncludePressedKeys>false</IncludePressedKeys>
  <EnableFastScroll>false</EnableFastScroll>
  <FastScrollingHotKeys>
    <VirtualKeys>Control</VirtualKeys>
    <VirtualKeys>Alt</VirtualKeys>
  </FastScrollingHotKeys>
  <ScrollSpeed>2</ScrollSpeed>
  <FastScrollSpeed>10</FastScrollSpeed>
</Settings>
```

If I try to deserialize this document I get an exception XmlException which tells me that the root element is missing. I've tried to set the XmlRootAttribute, tried to check the filenames and stream position. Everything is ok. Now I finally tried to read load the file through the XmlDocument class which works perfectly. Now I really don't know what happens. So you may take a look at the Load-method:

```
public static void Load(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        throw new ArgumentException("File not found.", "filename", new FileNotFoundException());

    //works
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(XmlReader.Create(File.OpenRead(filename)));
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);

    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        _instance = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Settings;
    }
}
```

Hopefully anyone got an idea.

Comment: What does your Settings class look like?

Comment: It would indeed be very helpful to have the Settings class. When I make a small class with the first two properties EnableHooking and IncludePressedKeys I get no error. So what is your question? The code seems to work, but you want a different solution?

Comment: no I don't want a different solution. I get an "root element missing" xmlexception with exactly this code. @Richard

Comment: Interesting, I tried it on OSX with Xamarin Studio. I will post my code as an answer.

Comment: The XlmDocument+XmlReader section leaves the File open, have you tried without this section?

Comment: Test move xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> to the first row and have just <Settings> as the nextrow

Answer (score 1):

When I use the following code (in which I added a simple version of the Settings class) on OSX with Xamarin Studio, I get no errors.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private static Settings _instance;

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Load ("Settings.xml");
        }

        public static void Load(string filename)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
                throw new ArgumentException("File not found.", "filename", new FileNotFoundException());

            //works
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(XmlReader.Create(File.OpenRead(filename)));
            Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
                _instance = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Settings;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public bool EnableHooking {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public bool IncludePressedKeys {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the value of _instance, the properties are set to the right values. I stripped the XML after the second property. The problem might be in more "complex" XmlElement "FastScrollingHotKeys". Could you post your Settings class, please?

Comment: When I run this on Win7 and VS Express 2010 it works just as well. Also when I set the project properties to Framework 2.0.